# split an equation

Tags: equations

I have the following equation

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
W_1=N_c^ * w_1^c + N_s^ * \left( {w_1^s + 2w_2^s + w_3^s} \right) \\
W_2= N_s^ * \left( {w_2^s + w_3^s + w_{11}^s + 4w_{22}^s + w_{33}^s + 4w_{12}^s + 4w_{23}^s + 2w_{13}^s} \right)+N_c^ * w_{11}^c \\
W_3=\left( {N_c^ * w_1^c + N_s^ * \left( {w_1^s + w_2^s} \right)} \right)
\end{array} \right.\,,
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How I can split into two lines the second equation (after the parenthese)?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the cases env (amsmath) to get the brace, and an aligned inside with `={} & ` alignment, and drop the left right constructions. Then lines can easily be broken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should load `amsmath` and use the `cases` environment; for splitting the second case, use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
W_1 = N_c^* w_1^c + N_s^* ( w_1^s + 2w_2^s + w_3^s ) \\
W_2 = \!\begin{aligned}[t]
      &N_s^* ( w_2^s + w_3^s + w_{11}^s + 4w_{22}^s + w_{33}^s + 4w_{12}^s + 4w_{23}^s + 2w_{13}^s )\\
      &+N_c^* w_{11}^c
      \end{aligned} \\
W_3 = N_c^* w_1^c + N_s^* ( w_1^s + w_2^s ) )
\end{cases}
,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that you're overusing braces and `\left`–`\right` pairs.

[image]

Comment: You forgot a `(` in the last line (ocd, ;-))

Answer (score 2):

I used `\hspace` to align the equations. I hope this is what you were looking for.

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
W_1=N_c^ * w_1^c + N_s^ * \left( {w_1^s + 2w_2^s + w_3^s} \right) \\
W_2=N_s^ * \left( {w_2^s + w_3^s + w_{11}^s + 4w_{22}^s + w_{33}^s + 4w_{12}^s + 4w_{23}^s + 2w_{13}^s} \right) \\ 
\hspace{1cm}+N_c^ * w_{11}^c \\
W_3=\left( {N_c^ * w_1^c + N_s^ * \left( {w_1^s + w_2^s} \right)} \right)
\end{array} \right.\,,
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that employs a single `aligned` environment.

[image]

Note that I've also removed the unnecessary `{...}` groupings and replaced all instances of `\left(` and `\right)` with `(` and `)` from the code you provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "aligned" environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  W_1 &=N_c^* w_1^c + N_s^* ( w_1^s + 2w_2^s + w_3^s ) \\
  W_2 &= N_s^* ( w_2^s + w_3^s + w_{11}^s + 4w_{22}^s + w_{33}^s + 4w_{12}^s + 4w_{23}^s \\
      &\quad + 2w_{13}^s ) +N_c^* w_{11}^c \\
  W_3 &=( N_c^* w_1^c + N_s^* ( w_1^s + w_2^s ) )
\end{aligned} 
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach as suggested egreg: but rather with`dcases` and `multlined` from package `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
W_1 = N_c^ * w_1^c + N_s^ * \left( {w_1^s + 2w_2^s + w_3^s} \right) \\
W_2 = \!\begin{multlined}[t]
        N_s^* \big(w_2^s + w_3^s + w_{11}^s + 4w_{22}^s + \\
        w_{33}^s + 4w_{12}^s + 4w_{23}^s + 2w_{13}^s \big) + N_c^ * w_{11}^c
        \end{multlined} \\
W_3 = \left(N_c^ * w_1^c + N_s^ * \left(w_1^s + w_2^s\right)\right)
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I correct my code according to suggestion in comments of Mico and Hooy.

Comment: I observe this too but didn't investigate so far, what is it source. Now I see that I should omit the ampersands. I will correct answer.

Comment: Also, the space before the `multlined` environment seems to be too big, which can easily be fixed by inserting `\!` before `\begin{multlined}`.